# Selenium can't find an element by class name

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get element from [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07B2STSLV) amazon page, which is average reviews rate for the product. And its located here:

[image]

In inspect console this part shows like that:

```
<span data-hook="rating-out-of-text" class="a-size-medium a-color-base">4.4 out of 5</span>
```

My code is:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromepath, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07B2STSLV')

driver.find_element_by_class_name("a-size-medium a-color-base")
```

desired output is:

```
4.4 out of 5
```

But it returns en error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".a-size-medium a-color-base"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=85.0.4183.121)
```

So apparently this way is not worked. I also tried several ways with css selector:

```
 driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.a-size-base a-nowrap")
```

And get element by xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reviewsMedley"]')
```

But both is not working

Any thoughts about how it can be gotten?

Comment: Use some waits after driver.get() and check for any iframes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 classes which you have used in `find_element_by_class_name` i.e. `a-size-medium` and `a-color-base` class_name selector doesen't support compound classes. Thats why it won't work

This `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.a-size-base a-nowrap")` also won't work because both classes `a-size-base` and `a-nowrap` belongs to same same tag i.e `<span>`

In short, you have to combine all classes which is in same tag using dot `.` which represents the class.

The css path will be look like-

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.a-size-base.a-nowrap").text
```

You can use compound class in xpath as given below

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='a-size-base a-nowrap']").text
```

There is one occurance of require element in your case so go with `find_element` instead of `find_elements`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't knew about compound classes before.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try this :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(“//span[@class=‘a-size-medium a-color-base’]”)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it. First, we click on the tag to open it up,grab it and then print out the element. Use waits for page loading and then print it's .text .

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#acrPopover > span.a-declarative > a"))).click()
elem=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.a-icon-row.a-spacing-small.a-padding-none > span")))
print(elem.text)
```

Outputs

```
4.4 out of 5
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```